# Android - Repeat sound in background X times with a Y delay each time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-intentservice

Rx with timer looks like the way to go. If you are not up for it Handler could work as well.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use any timer idea but what I would do most likely is encapsulating the beep in a separate Runnable class and then will call it from my activity/fragment/view whenever it is needed.

```
public final class BeepRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private final View view;
    private final int repeats;
    private final int interval;
    private int currentRepeat;

    public BeepRunnable(@NonNull View view, int repeats, int interval) {
        this.view = view;
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.view.getContext(), R.raw.beep);
        this.repeats = repeats;
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mp.start();
        if (currentRepeat < repeats) {
            // set to beep again
            currentRepeat = currentRepeat + 1;
            view.postDelayed(this, interval);
        }
        else {
            // beep is over, just reset the counter
            reset();
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        currentRepeat = 0;
    }

    public void destroy() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }

        mediaPlayer.release();
        view.removeCallbacks(this);
    }
}
```

Then in you activity for example

```
public final ApplicationActivity extends Activity {
    private BeepRunnable beepRunnable;
    ...
    // in your place where you need to start the beeping
    beepRunnable = new BeepRunnable(anyNonNullView, 4, 500);
    anyNonNullView.post(beepRunnable);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (beepRunnable != null) {
        beepRunnable.destroy();
        beepRunnable = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey there, thanks for your reply, I adapted part of your answer, the main issue I have here is to decide which is the best approach to make this... I will reply soon, thanks for your answer!

edit: why onDestroy? if you clean app from tasks the runnable also stops